Marker in osmdroid map
I created a mapView in AndroidStudio's project using the osmdroid library, in this way:
mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView)
mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK)
mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true)

then I created a marker on the map:
  thePoint = GeoPoint(lat, long)
    
  val mapController = mapView.controller
  mapController.setZoom(15.0)
  mapController.setCenter(thePoint)
    
  val marker = Marker(mapView).apply {
      position = thePoint                 
      title = label                      
      isDraggable = true                 
      icon = context.getDrawable(id)     
      setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM)
      }
 mapView.overlayManager.add(marker)

Now I see correctly the marker on my map.The problem is that the marker is not draggable... What I'm forgetting?

Finally, I resolved adding a custom mapView.setOnTouchListener

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
